# Mvc 4 to 5 upgrade issue - how to resolve Autofac security rules violation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, autofac, autofac-configuration

I upgraded my asp.net web app (targetFramework 4.5.2) from mvc 4 to 5 according to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2). The solution compiles without errors however at runtime I get:

*The inheritance security rules were violated when the member "Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver.GetService (System.Type)" was overwritten. The security access of the overriding method must match the security access of the overwritten method.*

I searched the forum but none of the related posts could help me to pin down the origin of the error.
Trying to upgrade Autofac.Mcv4 to 5 (as suggested in the posts) failed (-> Autofac.Mcv5 does not target frameWork 4.5.2). Changing the targetFramework to 4.6 and 4.6.1 also did not allow to install Autofac.Mcv5.

Below I have listed the relevant packages installed in the main project:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Autofac" version="3.5.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Autofac.Mvc4" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Autofac.WebApi2" version="3.4.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core" version="1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.LocalDB" version="1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.7" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.7" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax" version="2.0.30116.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="2.0.30116.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  ... and others
</packages>
```

Also note, that the solution has several projects (two have references to Autofac).
Any help to pin down the origin of or to solve the error would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to update the Autofac.Mvc4 package [to Autofac.Mvc5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Mvc5/).

Comment: I tried, but: -> Autofac.Mcv5 does not target frameWork 4.5.2. With targetFramework 4.6 and 4.6.1 I get the same error that Autofac.Mcv5 does not target frameWork  x.x.x

Answer (score 0):

As already posted in previous posts for Autofac to work with mvc5 also Autofac.mvc5 is needed. However in my case Autofac.mvc5 refused installation since my TargetFramwork was 4.5.2. When I upgraded to 4.6.1 Autofac.mvc5 still refused to install.

Simple reason: In my solution there are several projects and for one I forgot to upgrade the targetFramwork. Now Autofac.mvc5 installed properly, the *inheritance security rules violation error* is gone and the solution runs properly.

Comment: It sounds like the answer I have was the right answer - you needed to upgrade Autofac.Mvc5. Please accept my answer so I get credit for helping you. Thanks!